# Como trazer o total de cada coluna no FooterRow de um jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Estou usando a propriedade `grouping` do **jqGrid (4.6.0)** com **jQuery(1.11.0)**, mas só consegui gerar o total por coluna e não é isso que eu quero, gostaria do total geral.
O jqGrid contém a propriedade `grouping` que contém o `footerrow` que seria a fileira de rodapé do *Grid* (tabela). Alguém sabe como trazer os totais no `footerrow`?

As propriedades que estou usando no *Grid*:

```
$("#respostaRelatorio").jqGrid({
    url: urlRelatorio + "?" + dadosRelatorio,
    colModel: modeloColunas,
    mtype: "POST",
    altRows: true,
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    height: "auto",
    width: 1130,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ],
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: "#paginacao",
    sortorder: "asc",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    headertitles: true,
    loadui: "disable",
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    caption: "Resultados encontrados",
    deselectAfterSort: true,
    gridview: true,
    idPrefix: "id",
    rowTotal: 4000,
    sortable: true,
    toppager: true,
    resizable: true,
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: [ 'loginMedico' ],
        groupCollapse: false,
        groupOrder: [ 'asc' ],
        groupSummary: [ true ],
        groupDataSorted: true
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true
});

var modeloColunas = [
    { name: "loginMedico", index: "loginMedico", jsonmap: "loginMedico", label: "Login M&eacute;dico", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", summaryType: "count", summaryTpl: "total" },
    { name: "nomeMedico", index: "nomeMedico", jsonmap: "nomeMedico", label: "Nome do M&eacute;dico", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" },
    { name: "perfilMedico", index: "perfilMedico", jsonmap: "perfilMedico", label: "Perfil M&eacute;dico", sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
    { name: "tipoSolicitacao", index: "tipoSolicitacao", jsonmap: "tipoSolicitacao", label: "Tipo da Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" },
    { name: "cancelada", index: "cancelada", jsonmap: "cancelada", label: "Cancelada", sortable: true, sorttype: "int" },
    { name: "liberada", index: "liberada", jsonmap: "liberada", label: "Liberada", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryType: "sum" },
    { name: "negada", index: "negada", jsonmap: "negada", label: "Negada", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryType: "sum" },
    { name: "pendente", index: "pendente", jsonmap: "pendente", label: "Pendente", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryType: "sum" },
    { name: "total", index: "total", jsonmap: "total", label: "Total", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryTpl: "total"} ];
```

A imagem do meu *Grid*, observem que o `footerrow` aparece vazio: 
[image: tabela]

Comment: Coloca um exemplo no jsfiddle que fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Guilherme, como tanto aqui quanto no [SOE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332506/how-to-put-data-on-the-total-footerrow) te pediram um exemplo completo e funcional, te apresento o [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), busque sempre postar um exemplo autocontido e completo, incluindo dados de exemplo para receber respostas melhores mais rapidamente.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly utilizo frenquentemente a ferramenta jsfidlle.net, mas acontece que nessa ocasião nao há pagina em html, fazendo com que nao seja necessario utilizar o jsfidle sendo que o que eu fizer la seria basicamente o que passei pra voces aqui.

Comment: Você poderia criar um exemplo funcional somente com a `div` do jqGrid no campo HTML e todo o código JavaScript (incluindo dados de exemplo, que  foi o que faltou aqui), assim fica mais fácil brincar com seu exemplo e te dar uma resposta funcional. A ideia não é empurrar o jsfiddle, apenas te ajudar a obter mais respostas (não sei se a minha resposta resolveu o seu problema).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De uma olhada [nesse exemplo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum1.htm).

Basicamente você deve adicionar uma função `loadComplete` ao `jqGrid` para alimentar a linha de resumo:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    var somaCanceladas = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "cancelada", false, "sum");
    var somaLiberadas = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "liberada", false, "sum");
    var somaNegadas = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "negada", false, "sum");
    var somaPendentes = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "pendente", false, "sum");

    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        loginMedico: "Total:", 
        cancelada: somaCanceladas, 
        liberada: somaLiberadas, 
        negada: somaNegadas,
        pendente: somaPendentes 
    });
}
```

---

**Fonte:** [SOE - getting the sum using footerdata on jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142993/getting-the-sum-using-footerdata-on-jqgrid)

Comment: Desculpe pela demora em gratifica-lo com os pontos @AnthonyAccioly, houve uma mudança de projeto e fiquei um tempo sem mexer nesse código, fiz um teste rápido e o teu exemplo funcionou perfeitamente, desde já agradeço a sua atenção e ajuda.